# Close/Open export menu in JQuery Datatables on hover instead of onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using JQuery DataTables on which export option is working with click event. But instead of that I need to show export menu on hover of the export button.

Comment: Need code to reference and to see what you attempted and where you're getting confused.

Comment: Have you checked the doc:https://www.datatables.net/examples/index and what have you tried?